# Elegant ruby syntax to return the greater of two objects

Tags: ruby, comparison

Of course there are a thousand ways to get this done, but is the simplest (or most elegant) way to achieve this?

```
[4,8].max
```

That's actually not too shabby, but what would you do?

Comment: It is certainly very simple, but defining and array on the fly like this doesn't feel that great.

Comment: To me the array syntax is clearer than the ternary syntax.

Comment: But this is more DRY than the ternary syntax

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you don't want to spawn an array, there's the conditional operator:

```
max = a > b ? a : b
```

Answer (score 16):

Okay, I tested this out of curiosity:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

limit = 3000000

tstart_1 = Time.now()
(0..limit).each do |i; a,b, max|
  a = rand(9999999)
  b = rand(9999999)
  max = [a,b].max
end
puts "Array method: #{Time.now() - tstart_1} seconds"

tstart_2 = Time.now()
(0..limit).each do |i; a,b, max|
  a = rand(9999999)
  b = rand(9999999)
  max = (a > b) ? a : b
end

puts "Ternary method: #{Time.now() - tstart_2} seconds"
```

Output:

Array method: 1.746134 seconds

Ternary method: 1.002226 seconds

Comment: Mine was `Ternary: 1.452967` and  `Array: 3.147474`. Definitely going for the ternary :)

Comment: Hello, it's nearly 5 years later and I tested this again using Ruby 2.4.5p335. On 10 million iterations, the `[].min` method was slower by 0.06 seconds, or 60 milliseconds. Dividing that by 10 million, that means the `[].min` costs you an extra 60 _nanoseconds_. Depending on your circumstances, I think it's worth it.

Answer (score 10):

That's exactly why `Enumerable#max` has been defined for any class which implements `Comparable`. It's definitely the simplest. To really understad what's happening, you'd need to look how it's been implemented in the core library of your favourite Ruby implementation (and it's probably optimised).

Comment: This answer could benefit by supplying a specific example

Comment: The answer is saying that the example in the question is right; it doesn't need another example.